# This API project is not authorized to use this API when I reload the url

Tags: api, google-places-api

I am trying to use google places api with ***https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&key=.*** I have activated geocoding and geolocation api. When I first open the url, the data is visible but when i reload it I get an error : "This API project is not authorized to use this API."

Comment: Did you (1) enable the Places API on the Google Cloud console and (2) enable billing on your project?

Comment: I did not enable billing.

Comment: I see, then that's definitely the problem here. Enabling billing is mandatory for the Google Maps APIs to work, see https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started